# Is i possible to return only the top 10 series instead of all series

Tags: influxdb

I have the following query that returns the last ( 2m ) values

```
SELECT last("value") FROM "ROB" WHERE ("resource" = 'MY-SYS' AND "desc" = 'total-physical-utilization') AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time(2m), "label" fill(0) ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1
```

currently made up of 24 series, is it possible to only return the top 10 last (2m ) values sorted by descending order if possible with influx?

the data is made up like:

values are Time and value
tags are resource,desc and label

i think this could be done using supqueries? so i have tried:

```
SELECT top("value",label,5) FROM (SELECT last("value") FROM "ROB" WHERE ("resource" = 'MY-SYS' AND "desc" = 'total-physical-utilization') AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time(2m), "label" fill(0) ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1)
```

but this errors with subqueries must be ordered in the same direction as the query itself - so stuck again :(

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a perfect thing to solve with Flux -- the new query language for InlfuxDB. You can download/install the nightly builds of InfluxDB, Chronograf, and fluxd to try it out.

dg

Comment: and yet it seems that Flux does not solve this issue in any way